# double quotes inside double quotes in a string in unix

Tags: java, unix

I have a parameter as below:

```
parameter1=I am a line with spaces
```

I want to include this parameter in another parameter but surrounded with double quotes as an argument to java program.

```
java myProgram command="The line was "I am a line with spaces" always."
```

But when I do:

```
java myProgram command="The line was $parameter1 always."
```

Inside the java program I only get first token of the line i.e. "I"

So to include spaces also, I did:

```
java myProgram command="The line was "$parameter1" always."
```

Obviously now I will have to escape the quotes.

So I did:

```
java myProgram command="The line was \"$parameter1\" always."
```

But this is not working.

Am I escaping the double quotes wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be ending the string

```
java myProgram command="The line was \"$parameter1\" always."
```

change to

```
java myProgram command="The line was\"" + $parameter1 + "\" always."
```